# GDB break commands don't get executed in command files

Tags: debugging, gdb, riscv, openocd, segger-jlink

I have a debugging script that does the following:

1. sets two breakpoints. let's call them **start** and **end** breakpoints.
2. after starting, the script continues until **start** breakpoint is hit.
3. once **start** breakpoint is hit, I perform single-stepping until **end** breakpoint is hit.

This is my command file:

```
# end breakpoint
break 38
commands
    stop 1
    quit
end

# start breakpoint
break 50
commands
    set logging off
    set logging file log.txt
    set logging overwrite on
    set logging on
    printf "program counter: $pc"
end

continue

set $count = 0
set $steps = 15
while $count < $steps
    set $count = $count + 1
    next
end
```

To clarify, once I start my debugging session the program stops at the beginning of *main*; that's why I have *continue* in the script to jump to the **start** breakpoint.

The problem is that the break command does not get executed whenever the breakpoint is hit. This is what I get in the console:

```
++next

Breakpoint 23, main () at ..\..\hello_world.c:50
50      test_byte++;
++set $count = $count + 1
++next
51      test_byte++;
++set $count = $count + 1
++next
```

Nothing is printed to the console or to the logging file. However, when I write the same break command directly to the console and step manually it works.

I am debugging a VEGAboard with RISC-V using a JLink debugger and openOCD.

**Update:**

I fount that the issue is somehow with having next in the loop. So whenever I get rid of the loop and simply hardcode the number of *next* commands, the break command gets executed successfully.

This behavior is still odd and I hope somebody has an explanation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501121/how-to-execute-finish-and-then-another-command-from-inside-commands and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261404/how-to-prevent-gdb-to-stop-after-next-command. The function worked for me when I was using "finish". And "hookpost" helped we with next.